# What happens during serialization in java, if two object refrences are pointing to the same serializable Object?

Tags: java, serialization

What happens during serialization in java, if two object refrences are pointing to the same serializable Object? **Does the Serializable Objects get saved twice ?**
for example :

```
    class King implements java.io.Serializable {
        private String name="Akbar";
    }

    class Kingdom implements java.io.Serializable {
        King goodKing=new King();
        King badKing=goodKing;
    }

    public class TestSerialization {
        public static void serializeObject(String outputFileName,
                                           Object serializableObject) throws IOException {
            FileOutputStream fileStream=new FileOutputStream(outputFileName);
            ObjectOutputStream outStream=new ObjectOutputStream(fileStream);
            outStream.writeObject(serializableObject);
            outStream.close();
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Kingdom kingdom=new Kingdom();
            try {
                TestSerialization.serializeObject("Kingdom1.out", kingdom);
            }catch(IOException ex) {
                ex.getMessage();
            }
        }
    }
```

Now, whether only one object state is saved for both *goodKing* and *badKing* refrences or the King object get saved twice ?

Comment: Have you tried to save the class with one and two references and compared the file size of the result?

Comment: Try to deserialize Kingdom, and see whether goodKing and badKing point to the same King. If they are, then having one King in Kingdom1.out is sufficient do deserialize the Kingdom. From this, we can guess that only one object state is saved.

Comment: @Smutje The generated file is always showing to be of size 1KB

Comment: @fajarkoe, I tried that and there was no problem with that and also I generated two different serialized files, one with only one refrence i.e.,**goodKing** and another with both the refrences as shown above and there was absolutely no difference in both the files when i compared their Hexadecimal contents.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The documentation for [`ObjectOutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html) says what happens:

> The default serialization mechanism for an object writes the class of the object, the class signature, and the values of all non-transient and non-static fields. References to other objects (except in transient or static fields) cause those objects to be written also. **Multiple references to a single object are encoded using a reference sharing mechanism so that graphs of objects can be restored to the same shape as when the original was written.**

*(My emphasis)*

E.g., if you have multiple references to a single object, when the graph is reconstituted, you end up with multiple references to a single reconstituted version of that object, not references to multiple equivalent instances of it.

Of course, if the container being serialized implements a different mechanism, the behavior is dictated by that mechanism, not the default one.

So for instance, if we have `Thing` and `Test`:

`Thing.java`:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Thing implements Serializable {
    private Map<String,String> map1;
    private Map<String,String> map2;

    public Thing() {
        this.map1 = new HashMap();
        this.map2 = this.map1; // Referring to same object
    }

    public void put(String key, String value) {
        this.map1.put(key, value);
    }

    public boolean mapsAreSameObject() {
        return this.map1 == this.map2;
    }
}
```

`Test.java`:

```
import java.io.*;

public class Test implements Serializable {

    public static final void main(String[] args) {
        try
        {
            // Create a Thing
            Thing t = new Thing();
            t.put("foo", "bar");

            // Write it out
            ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("foo"));
            os.writeObject(t);
            os.close();
            os = null;

            // Read it in
            Thing t2;
            ObjectInputStream is = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("foo"));
            t2 = (Thing)is.readObject();
            is.close();
            is = null;

            // Same underlying map for both properties?
            System.out.println("t2.mapsAreSameObject? " + t2.mapsAreSameObject());
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

And run `java Test`, we get:

```
t2.mapsAreSameObject? true
```

...because both of `Thing`'s members, `map1` and `map2` end up pointing to a single `HashMap` instance.

Comment: You mean to say that irrespective of the no of refrences to a single object, only one copy of that object will be save during serualization and during serialization, every refrence to that single object will be reconstructed back as in original class.

Comment: @AmiteshRai: Right. Or rather, that's what the documentation says. :-) And again, that's with default serialization; if a container implements its own serialization, it could do something else (although doing something else would be strange and surprising).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - I don't quite understand.. Why would references come into picture during serialization?. Serialization is more-or-less dumping the object. How many references point to the object shouldn't matter. right?

Comment: @TheLostMind: It matters quite a lot *if* those references are part of the graph being serialized. Look at the code example above: If serialization didn't handle the fact that `map1` and `map2` refer to the *same* object, we'd serialize the `HashMap` twice (rather than serializing it once and indicating that both `map1` and `map2` point to that one object), and when reconstituting the graph we'd break it, with `map1` and `map2` pointing to separate-but-equivalent maps.