# Strange behaviour on inner array serialization

Tags: java, arrays, serialization

I want to serialize large amount of digits into the file.
So I decided to use some wrapper object for the array of primitives and serialize it in cycle.
But in process I met some interesting behavior: despite I changing values in the inner array I actually serialize the first copy each time.
So, can somebody clarify this situation or find my mistake? :)

My base object:

```
public class PortionWrapper implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -55857686305273843L;
    private long[] portion;

    public PortionWrapper() {   }
    public PortionWrapper(long[] portion) {  this.portion = portion; }

    //--------------------------------------------------
    public long[] getPortion() {             return portion; }
    public void setPortion(long[] portion) { this.portion = portion; }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Wrapper{ portion=" + Arrays.toString(portion) "}";
    }
}
```

My serialization process:

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("sequences/seq.ser")
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
long[] a1 = {1L, 2L, 3L};
oos.writeObject(new PortionWrapper(a1));
a1[0] = 0;
a1[1] = 0;
a1[2] = 0;
oos.writeObject(new PortionWrapper(a1));
oos.close();
```

And deserialization:

```
try (ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("sequences/seq.ser")))
{
    do {
        portionWrapper = (PortionWrapper)ois.readObject();
        System.out.println(portionWrapper);
    } while (true);
} catch (EOFException e) {
}
```

Output:

```
PortionWrapper{portion=[1, 2, 3]}
PortionWrapper{portion=[1, 2, 3]}
```

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I don't think it's a matter of preserving the identity at all. It's a matter of not setting one's objects carefully, and ending up with undesired (and unexpected) alias as the result.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight You seem to be describing identity with _not setting one's objects carefully_.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24136720/what-happens-during-serialization-in-java-if-two-object-refrences-are-pointing ?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis You are right!!! Thank you very much for finding the right duplicate.